# Java keystore for android is missing

Tags: java, android, keystore, recover

My backup harddrive is completely broken, and my working pc is after format since that time. I've checked drive by some recovery software, but i can't find any .keystore files on list. Is there any other way to recover keystore? I need this to update my app...

Answer (score 0):

If you lost your keystore file,there is no way that you can update your app in google play and it will cause a signature error.
The only way is create an app with a new package name and upload it to play.

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Comment: I know, but i was asking about recover of this keystore.

Comment: the only way is recover your keystore from your pc drive. Unfortunately no other ways.

Comment: DO you know good free software that may find this file? I'm using "Free Any Data REcovery" but it didn't found any keystore file, and i'm sure i had about 3 of them.